# does anyone know how to login without credit card informations

Tags: apple-store

[image][image][image]I have already made my Apple ID through Game center instead of doing it first on the App store. Now I want to download another app so I have to log in my apple ID to app store then when I have logged in something popped saying "This apple ID has not yet been used in the itunes store" then theres options Cancel or Review when i click the review one theres this terms and conditions then agree or back only. i chose agree then the credit card billing appear how can i login without entering credit card informations? And can i use the apple id i made at the game center? i think its just the same, isnt? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an Account (or Apple-ID, iTunes-Account, GameCenter-ID etc.) you have to login into iTunes using your credentials from a Computer (Mac or PC), there you have the Option to select "none" in the Billings-Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I figure you need to create a new Apple ID. I just remembered that the None option is hidden when you update a Game Center ID. Alternatively, (not reccommended) you could enter phony info.

Comment: Hello! when the billing informations popped thers just three options unfortunately theres no "none"

Comment: @Airie Could you tell me the 3 options when you hit review?

Comment: hahah. im sorry i mean theres just options like "Visa and 2 other credit card" theres no none option... so i cant click none :(

Comment: @Airie could you please send me a screenshot? Make sure to crop out personal info

Comment: posted it look at the question. hope u can help me. thanks!

Comment: @Airie Updated question, wish I could say some way to get None to show up.

Comment: @Airie There's no solution to migrating a Game Center account to an Apple ID without billing info. Moderator, sorry for the extended discussion, I need 1 more rep to move it to chat.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple as of (Last Modified: Jul 14, 2014) you do not need credit card for Apple Store.

Apple also recommends to have only one ID, for game center and all others.

You will be asked for payment information if you use products that are not free.

Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account [without](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534) a
credit card or other payment method.

There are 2 possibilities:

One is you already have a Apple Id, and you want to [remove the Payment information.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1918)

Second one is you are creating a new account (without Payment information.)

[image: no payment]